# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - how to check if tag element exists in findelement

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to check whether the element in tag exist or no. For instance I have :

```
//span[.='System']/following-sibling::span[@style="display: none;"]
```

Not for any tag an element `style="display: none;"` is exist

So,

I want to put If else handler using Boolean to check if the element exist or no.

I used before:

```
Boolean elmn = Login.driver.findElements
                        (By.xpath("//span[.='System']/following-sibling::span[@style=\"display: none;\"]")).size() == 0;
if (elmn)
    exit;
else 
   Assert.fail()
```

But something not working properly. Is there any suggestions how can I check if the element exist inside tag or not?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception ? And, are you trying to check if there are elements with `style` attribute as `display:none;` ?

Comment: Nope. This statement always false. But I've checked in the FireBug I can see this element

Comment: As per your code you trying to check if there are elements with `style attribute` as `display:none;`. Am I correct ? Or are you just checking **if a certain element is displayed or not?**

Comment: I've checked my xpath value recently...It's strange when I process a code : org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath But when I check xpath in FireBug it's displayed...

Comment: I'm trying to check if there are tag span with style=display:none. So, I have the html:  <div class="test1">
<span data-bind="text: $data.name">System</span>
<br/>
<span class="deleted" style="display: none;">Deleted</span>
</div>
<div class="test1">
<span data-bind="text: $data.name">System</span>
<br/>
<span class="deleted">Deleted</span>
</div> . There 2 elements with the same classname but have difference in the attribues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()` to the grab the attribute value and do a check

```
WebElement elmn = Login.driver.findElements
                        (By.xpath("Xpath to identify element without the attribute"))
if (elmn.getAttribute("style").equals("display: none;"))
    exit;
else 
   Assert.fail()
```

Comment: I guess, `elmn.getAttribute("style")=="display: none;"` must be replaced with `elmn.getAttribute("style").equals("display: none;")` in case of comparing two strings.

Comment: You are correct @Subh. I am doing `value` comparison not `reference` so `.equals` should be used. Thanks for the correction.. Edited